# How to save default value for application without files

Tags: c#, winforms, collections

I'm trying to save default setting using `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773718/how-to-save-default-context-settings-in-c) and  according to it I can use this and save my setting in collection even after reloading programm, but currently I'm stuck. I can't take this setting from collection.

Here is my code:

```
StringCollection defValueArr = new StringCollection();//collection for saving def values
public bool SaveDefaultValueCollection(NumericUpDown numBox)
{
    bool saved = false;
    try
    {
        if (!saved)
        {
            string[] defArray = new string[1];
            defArray[0] = numBox.Value.ToString();
            defValueArr.AddRange(defArray);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and methos for getting def setting

```
public int GetDefaultVolume()
{
    //here i'll got error
    //invalid array item - out of range item
    return Convert.ToInt32(defValueArr[0]);
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add a resource file.. you cannot just instantiate a collection and hope for the best.. Re-read the question you linked.

Comment: so in any way i must to record result to file? and i can't save information in collection and get it after reloading programm?

Comment: Ask yourself.. how would that work (if it were possible)?

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually saving stuff using `Settings.Default`. Just using the collection does not do anything for you.